# データベースの複数回インストールの件

Tags: wordpress

Wordpress のインストールで、MariaDBをダウンロードしました。
ですが、Wordpress のインストールが上手くいかず、インストール手順を一から何度か試しています。
この場合、毎度MariaDBをダウンロードしている工程は何か不具合を生じさせますか？

Comment: 「Wordpressのインストールがうまくいかない」の方を質問した方が解決に近づきそうです。

Comment: 「インストールを繰り返す」と「ダウンロードを繰り返す」では意味合いが異なります。また、「インストールを一から試す」は「失敗した環境を残したままやり直す」と「まずは削除で元に戻してやり直す」のどちらでしょうか？

Comment: 前者の、失敗した環境を残したままやり直す、の方になります。本当は一連の流れを削除して何もしていない環境に戻してから、再度やってみようとは思いましたが、パソコン内のどこにあるかがわからず、削除できずにいます。

Comment: 基本的にソフトウェアを削除するためにはinstallした方法があるようにuninstallする方法が存在します。どのOSでもそうですが、ファイルを削除すればOKとかそういうものではなく、正しい手順をまずは学ぶとよいでしょう

Comment: 勉強になります。ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

プラットフォーム（ Windows / Linux / その他 ）が何か書いてありませんので、以下は推測となりますが

ダウンロードするだけならあなたの記憶装置の容量を食う以外の悪影響はないと思います（不具合とはいいがたい）

ダウンロード後インストールを複数回試みるのは何か不具合を引き起こす可能性が０ではありません。でもまあよくできたインストーラは同一プロダクト (MariaDB) の同一バージョンの複数回インストールくらいでは問題を生じさせることはないと思って大丈夫です。（同一プロダクトの異バージョンを更新インストールではなく同時に共存させようとかすると困ることはあるかもしれません）

Comment: 情報不足で申し訳ありません。プラットフォームはLinuxです。